# How do I center the ImageButton ( its a image and a button) in the middle of the webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've tried different codes  but I was not able to centralize ImageButton for Paypal in visual studio.
code is below

```
 <table> 
     <tr>

     <td>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="CheckoutImageBtn" runat="server" 
        ImageUrl="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" 
                  Width="145" AlternateText="Check out with PayPal" 
                  OnClick="CheckoutBtn_Click" 
                  BackColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="0" />
     </td>

     </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Margin Auto Property

```css
.center_div{
margin:0 auto;
height:100px;
width:100px;
background:green;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="center_div">
Iam Center

</div>
```

Comment: Try this 
`<center>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" CssClass="centerButton" />
</center>`